# Why does x = 12345678901234567890 return "x is less than y" when y = 1?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int x;
int y;
printf("What's x? ");
scanf("%d",&x);

printf("What's y? ");
scanf("%d",&y);

if (x < y)
{
    printf("x is less than y\n");
}
else if (x > y)
{
    printf("x is greater than y\n");
}
else
{
    printf("x and y are equal");
}

return 0;
}
```

Input:
12345678901234567890
1

Output:
x is less than y

expecting program to return "x is greater than y" when x = 12345678901234567890 and y = 1

Comment: Are you aware that data types have limits on the values they can store?

Comment: What's the value limit of a declared int, when one is not specified?

Comment: On most systems, `int` is 32 bits. The maximum value is `2,147,483,647`

Comment: Implementation-specific, depending on compiler and target architecture. However, the particular value in question is too large to be represented even by a (signed) 64-bit integer. It's likely that `sizeof(int)` on your system is 4. That's the most common, which means 32-bits.

Comment: If it's 64 bits, the max would be `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. That's 19 digits, you entered 20 digits.

Comment: In the standard header file `limits.h`. For `int` it would be `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%d` conversion specifier requires the corresponding `scanf` argument to be a pointer to `int`.  The decimal digit sequence `12345678901234567890` corresponds to a number that is very likely to be outside the range that your `int` (probably a 32-bit type) can represent.  Supposing that it is indeed out of range, the behavior of your program is undefined when processing the input specified.  That means anything can happen, as far as the language spec is concerned.

C23 7.23.6.2/10:

> the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the
> first argument following the format argument that has not already
> received a conversion result. **If this object does not have an
> appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be
> represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.**

(Emphasis added.)